# Entity Framework Automated Migration multiple context

Tags: entity-framework

I have two databases. When I make a change to one of my dbcontext (adding a new DbSet) it should automatically apply the changes to the correct databases when runnnig my webapplication. So the new table should be added. Therefore I have added two configuration classes. One for each database/context.

However using the initializers like below the changes are always applied to the second context/database. Because this is the latest initializer configured.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DomainReadModelContext, DomainConfiguration>());
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<WebsiteReadModelContext, WebsiteConfiguration>());
```

I also tried it in the web.config

```
<contexts>
  <context type="Domain.ReadModels.DomainReadModelContext, Domain.ReadModels">
    <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[Domain.ReadModels.DomainReadModelContext, Domain.ReadModels], [Website.Migrations.Domain.DomainConfiguration, Website-WebAppMainModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]], EntityFramework" />
  </context>
  <context type="Website.ReadModels.WebsiteReadModelContext, Website.ReadModels">
    <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[Website.ReadModels.WebsiteReadModelContext, Website.ReadModels], [Website.Migrations.Website.WebsiteConfiguration, Website-WebAppMainModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]], EntityFramework" />
  </context>
</contexts
```

When applying the changes via the package manager it works as it should be. The table gets added to my domaincontext database.

```
Update-Database -config DomainConfiguration
```

Is this because this isn't supported or am I doing it wrong? Now it seems to work only for the latest initializer registered.

For the update I have scaffolded a Migration using the Add-Migration command in the package manager.

```
Add-Migration AddUniquePersonReadModelMigration -config DomainConfiguration
```

This generated following class for me.

```
public partial class AddUniquePersonReadModelMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "UniquePersonReadModels",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    PersonId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    DisplayName = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(p => p.PersonId)
            .Index(p => p.DisplayName, true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("UniquePersonReadModels", new[] { "PersonId" });
        DropIndex("UniquePersonReadModels", new[] { "DisplayName" });
        DropTable("UniquePersonReadModels");
    }
}
```

So my question is does entity framework support the migrations for multiple contexts using initializers? If not, it would be a nice feature when the migrations can be handled for multiple contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem by moving the Migration folder from my website to separate assemblies.

So instead of the following:

```
Solution/
    DomainReadModels/
        DomainContext.cs
        Classes........
    WebsiteReadModels/
        WebsiteContext.cs
        Classes........
    Website/
        Migration/
            AddSomeTableToDomainMigration.cs
            AddSomeTableToWebsiteMigration.cs
            WebsiteReadModelsConfiguration.cs
            DomainReadModelsConfiguration.cs
        Websitefiles...
```

I changed my solution to:

```
Solution/
    DomainReadModels/
        Migration/
            DomainReadModelsConfiguration.cs
            AddSomeTableToDomainMigration.cs
        DomainContext.cs
        Classes........
    WebsiteReadModels/
        Migration/
            AddSomeTableToWebsiteMigration.cs
            WebsiteReadModelsConfiguration.cs
        WebsiteContext.cs
        Classes........
    Website/
        Websitefiles...
```

Now the only disadvantage is I have to switch projects in the package manager console...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you are using two contexts `DomainReadModelContext` and `WebsiteReadModelContext` and each of these contexts uses a different database. If this is the case, then you can certainly have an initializer for each context and it will be run the first time that context is used against the given database. In other words, the initializer for `DomainReadModelContext`  will be run the first time that `DomainReadModelContext` is used against the domain model database, and the initializer for `WebsiteReadModelContext` will be run the first time that `WebsiteReadModelContext` is used against the domain model database.

If both contexts are using the same database then this will not work. Using Migrations for multiple contexts that access the same database is not supported in EF5, but we're working on it for EF6.

Comment: I'm using different databases. Set both initializers, but somehow the table is added to my websiteReadmodelContext and it should be added to the domainreadmodelcontext database.

Comment: initializers are set in App_start global.asax. Website hits the websiteReadmodelContext first... Domainreadmodelcontext is only hit when making changes

Comment: Then that sounds like a bug. If you could create a repro and file a bug on CodePlex (http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic) that would be great.

Comment: Just trying to clarify...
Setting initializers is not what triggers init. It's the database activitiy from the context. So DomainReadModelContext won't trigger the update until that first change is made. Is the schema change NOT happeneing at that time either? If it *is* happening then but you don't want to wait,you can force initialization on each context and not wait for the db activity.

Comment: Domain is also hit when trying to make a change. Use it for some cross aggregate domain validations. So the first hit will always be a query. Forcing is not what I want. It only has to be done when necessary. I can force it by doing it in package mananager or some SQL script.

Comment: I mean you can force it in code. You can control when the init happens.