# Entity Framework 5, Code First and Add-Migration Using a Second DbContext Not Working

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, nuget, code-first

I have a problem with "Add-Migration" instruction when the Table definition is in a new DbContext Class.

I created a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Application in Visual Studio 2012.

I ran the "Enable-Migrations", "Add-Migration mig1", "Update-Database". Everything was smooth.

Than, I added a new class inheriting the DbContext to the Models folder. I was hoping that "Add-Migration mig2" will notice the new table definition. But it does not.

Any ideas why?

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Models
{
    public class CmsContext: DbContext
    {
        public CmsContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<CustomItem> CustomItems { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("CustomItems")]
    public class CustomItem
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Ordinal { get; set; }
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public String Content { get; set; }
        public String FilePath { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName {NameOfTheContextType}`? I think at the moment migrations are enabled only for the first context and since there is no changes to this class nothing is happening. btw. I believe that multi-tenancy is really supported in EF6 and not in EF5 (see: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations)

Comment: Pawel - Thank you very much. **Indeed EF5 "Enable-Migrations" can work only one context at a time**. Following your instructions, the complete command is "Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName {xyz} **-Force**". Running the command "Enable-Migrations -Force" (without the specific context name) will result the console error: "More than one context type was found in the assembly...". Another relevant  SO thread can be found here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281492/entity-framework-automated-migration-multiple-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-tenancy is not supported in EF5 but is supported in EF6 where you can specify a context for which you want to enable migrations for like this:

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName {NameOfTheContextType}
```

See the [migrations multi-tenancy feature spec](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations) on the [Entity Framework codeplex site](https://entityframework.codeplex.com).